# Throw exception from ClassLibrary

Tags: c#, exception, handler, throw

When you try to throw a new exception from ClassLibrary to another project, Visual studio will open Class1.cs and handle the error.

**My question is: How can I throw the exception from the called function(ClassLibrary) to the Caller Function(Windows Form)?**

**Note** : I don't want to throw an original exception , i want to throw a custom exception like this

```
throw new Exception("change your password")
```

Comment: What is `Class1.cs` in your application? Is it inside ClassLibrary Project? or application project

Comment: Class1.cs is in ClassLibrary Project.

Comment: Visual Studio will only "handle" the error if you include it with your shipping program.  That's not very common.

Comment: Do you import `ClassLibrary` to the second project? How do you import it?

Comment: You can use the entire code `throw new Exception("change your password");` inside `catch` block

Comment: No i didn't , just i added the Dll file to WinFrom reference ,, but visual studio has opened class1.cs !!!!!

Comment: Your question needs some clarification.
Do you mean you want to throw an exception to the Visual Studio rather than the runtime program?

Comment: Exactly, i want to see "Exception handler message" on my code while debugging WindowsFormsApplication1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a long *long* way to go in your basic understanding of Exceptions and Exception handling, I would highly encourage you to pick up a resource on C# development.

To solve your immediate issue, I think the answer you are looking for lies in:

> Visual Studio Toolbar->Debug->Exceptions

Visual studio will "break" on various exceptions that you specify, and anything not checked will simply run through the course of whatever try/catch block handles that type of exception.

When you mention:

> Note : I don't want to throw an original exception , i want to throw a
>   custom exception like this

```
throw new Exception("change your password")
```

That is the **definition** of a generic exception, **not** a custom exception. To define a custom exception, you should subclass Exception:

```
public class MyCustomException : Exception 
{
   ...
}
```

and then throw it as such:

```
throw new MyCustomException("Some description of what went wrong");
```

Then, to get Visual Studio to "break" on that specific exception, find your exception in Toolbar->Debug->Exceptions window (under CLR exceptions) and mark the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
throw YourExceptionYouWantToThrow;
```

or

```
throw new TypeOfExceptionYouWantToThrow();
```

The exception will be caught by the next catch block. If there is no try-catch, the application will crash. In case of a visual studio debugger, the debugger will open Class1.cs and display you the source of the exception. 
You can catch it with something like that:

```
private void ButtonClick(...)
{
    try{
        Class1.MethodCall();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle the exception here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but , i don't want to use try-catch block - i want to handle the error in design time by visual studio .

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "design time by visual studio"

Comment: i mean debug-time in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

If you have a source of ClassLibrary project (include with Class1.cs) and you have used the project dll in debug folder, this problem will happen

So if i send to my friend the project assembly (dll only) , the problem will not encounter for him

Is someone have a clearly idea ?

Comment: Source is stored in .pdb files, which should be shipped with your .dll if you want to debug in a libraries source...if that is remotely what you are describing.

Answer (score -1):

```
try
{
    YourClass.Function();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // throw your Exception
}
```